# NoIR raspberry set the blue filter

Tags: raspicam, raspi-config

I just got my NoIR raspberry pi camera and it comes with a blue filter.
More info  [here:](http://www.raspberrypi.org/whats-that-blue-thing-doing-here/)
But I don't know how to place it.

The lens comes with a blue label too and I don't know if that is a blue filter as well or just a label that I should remove. Here there is a pic of the [label](http://ep.yimg.com/ay/yhst-27389313707334/raspberry-pi-noip-5mp-night-vision-camera-module-8.gif).

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Good question. I cannot tell from the picture, though it does more or less look like protective foil to me on the picture given. Does it look that it is detachable (besides the flap that is really inviting to remove it)?

Comment: @Ghanima the protective foil does invite one to remove it, but if it were a blue filter what's the point in providing the square one?

Now I am more into finding out how to place/set the blue square since I already detached the protective foil.

Comment: I'd guess that cutting a rectangular shape for that filter takes the least effort for the vendor while still maintaining a large degree of freedom for the user concerning the mounting of the filter (e.g. using adhesives outside the necessary free aperture).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is how my two NoIR cameras came.

Remove protective cover and manually place the blue filter with sellotape etc.

Comment: Did you placed the whole blue square filter or cut a piece and put it on the lens with tape @rob??

Comment: the whole thing